# Security exception when launching c# app from network location

Tags: c#, .net, security, exception, networking

i have a very small utilty app written in c# that works fine on my local machine but if i put it on a network drive and try to run it from there i get the following securityException..

Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Anyone know why and how i can fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is default behaviour for earlier .NET versions. It was 'fixed' in 3.5 SP1. [Here is a link](http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2008/08/13/net-framework-3-5-sp1-allows-managed-code-to-be-launched-from-a-network-share.aspx).

If you need to use an earlier version, the only solution is to [adjust the trustlevel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815147) of the assembly (on each PC that uses it). Usually no fun.

Comment: Really, a bug? or more a CAS feature?

Comment: It was a design 'feature'. The default policies are changed now (3.5SP1 and 4.x). See the link.

Comment: CAS feature. The default setting for network locations was changed in 3.5 SP1.

Comment: Thank you all for these precisions (the promised +1 :-) )